# Racket error in string-replace function?

Tags: list, racket, wrapper

I am writing
a function string-replace which consumes a string, a target character, and a
replacement character. The function produces a new string, which is identical to the
consumed string with all occurrences of the target character (if any) replaced with the
replacement character. For example, `(string-replace "word" #\o #\y) ⇒ "wyrd"`

Note:
I cannnot use any built-in string functions other than `string->list` and `list->string`

My code looks like

```
  (define(list-replace input-list from-char to-char)
     (string-replace input-list from-char to-char))

 (define(string-replace input-string from-char to-char)
  (list->string(string-replace(string->list input-string) from-char to-char)))
```

To check I enter 
      `(string-replace "word" #\o #\y)` I am getting an error `string->list: expects a string, given (cons #\w (cons #\o (cons #\r (cons #\d empty))))`

Can someone help me in this code to make it work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more descriptive. It should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will have meaning for a future reader who sees it in a search result. *Racket* is available from the tag you used, and *beginner error?* is totally meaningless.

Comment: ok done edited.Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `'for/list'` to create a modified list (from the input-string converted to list). The modified list can then be converted to modified string:

```
(define (string-replace input-string from-char to-char)
  (list->string
   (for/list ((item (string->list input-string)))   
     (if (equal? item from-char)
         to-char
         item))))

(string-replace "word" #\o #\y)
"wyrd"
```